# Revision 26.1.0 Release Support Library failed to instantiate AppCompatTextView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-support-library

When using 26.1.0 revision I get a render error in the layout preview stating:
The following classes could not be instantiated
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView

> java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getValue(Resources_Delegate.java:788)
>     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1286)   at
>   android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.loadFont(ResourcesCompat.java:212)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.getFont(ResourcesCompat.java:206)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getFont(TintTypedArray.java:119)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.updateTypefaceAndStyle(AppCompatTextHelper.java:208)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelper.java:152)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelperV17.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelperV17.java:38)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:81)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:71)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)   at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.CustomBar.(CustomBar.java:95)
>     at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.StatusBar.(StatusBar.java:67)
>     at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.createStatusBar(Layout.java:224)
>     at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.(Layout.java:146)

What can be happening?